# angular date input (html) model (value) does not get updates when input is changed

Tags: angularjs, date

H have 2 angular date inputs. dateFrom and DateTo. they are both date objects but when i change the input to another day, the scope still shows the "new Date" value... not the updated value?

**JS**

```
//set dates
    $scope.getFromDate = function() {
        $scope.dateFrom = new Date();
    }
    $scope.getToDate = function() {
        $scope.dateTo = new Date();
    }`
```

**VIEW**

```
        <div>
        <label class="item item-input" style="margin-left:0">
            <span class="input-label">van</span>
            <input type="date" ng-model="dateFrom" ng-init="getFromDate()">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input" style="margin-left:0">
            <span class="input-label">tot</span>
            <input type="date" ng-model="dateTo" ng-init="getToDate()">
        </label>
        {{dateFrom}}
```

later in another function i send the dateFrom and dateTo variable as follow

```
    $scope.getComp = function() {
    var dateTo = $scope.dateTo.getDate()+'-'+$scope.dateTo.getMonth()+1+'-'+$scope.dateTo.getFullYear();
    var dateFrom = $scope.dateFrom.getDate()+'-'+$scope.dateFrom.getMonth()+1+'-'+$scope.dateFrom.getFullYear();
```

but even if I have changed the to inputs on the view to another dates.. dateFrom and dateTo still show the "current" date?

Comment: How are you changing dates? Is it an event outside of angular .. like click event, third party script , socket connection, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `ng-init` in your inputs.

Also `date` input expects a date in `yyyy-MM-dd` format so it's better to initialize it with `$scope.dateFrom = $filter("date")(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');`

So simply:

```js
function Ctrl($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.dateFrom = $filter("date")(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  $scope.dateTo = $filter("date")(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <label class="item item-input" style="margin-left:0">
      <span class="input-label">van</span>
      <input type="date" ng-model="dateFrom">
    </label>
    <div>dateFrom : {{dateFrom}}</div>
    <Br/>
    <label class="item item-input" style="margin-left:0">
      <span class="input-label">tot</span>
      <input type="date" ng-model="dateTo">
    </label>
    <div>dateTo : {{dateTo}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok nice, but the problem still remains. If i set the date to another date in the view... when i console.log the dateFrom or DateTo from the controller i dont get the updated dates i get the now date

Comment: yes thanks,, i got the solution now. i need to inject the variables as parameters using a click event if i need "modified" data. thanks